How to train a simple vision transformer model on a custom dataset similar to CIFAR10?
I am attempting to train the following vision transformer model: https://github.com/tintn/vision-transformer-from-scratch on a custom dataset formatted similarly to CIFAR10.
This code is configured to train on CIFAR10, and I have done this, but I created a separate directory called "custom-cifar" with 10 folders, corresponding to each CIFAR class, that contain custom images that are formatted properly. I also converted the images in this directory to a binary file, called out.bin, in which each row represents an image. The file is formatted like the CIFAR data (see https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar.html).
No matter what I try, I am unable to correctly modify data.py to train on my custom data.
I want to train and test on the custom dataset.
In data.py, I tried setting the folder pathname equal to trainset, and I also set the pathname for out.bin equal to the trainset variable.
I tried creating a new dataloader class for the custom data, and modifying the existing one, but to no avail.
How can I modify the data.py dataloader so that it works on my custom dataset?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
